# How can I pass Session variables from a classic php file to a CakePHP file?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm setting up some sort of hub for API calls (complet.php), which will redirect via header the requests to the correct CakePHP controller & action.

For this to work I have to use classic sessions to pass my variables between files but there is a problem : They are not stored in the CakePHP session.

I have already tried putting the session name (included below) before session_start but it doesn't work

session name and start (complet.php) :

```php
session_name('CAKEPHP');
session_start();
```

redirect function (complet.php) :

```php
function redirect($url){
    if($url != null){
        header('Location: '.$url);
        exit();
    }
    else{
        http_response_code(500);
    }
}
```

First line of test function (CakePHP file) :

```php
dd($this->getRequest()->getSession()->read('m_email'));
```

The expected output is `jose@test.fr` but the actual output is `null`.

session_get_cookie_params (complet.php // CakePHP file) :

```
array(5) { ["lifetime"]=> int(0) ["path"]=> string(1) "/" ["domain"]=> string(0) "" ["secure"]=> bool(false) ["httponly"]=> bool(false) }

//

\src\Controller\UserController.php (line 69)
[
    'lifetime' => (int) 0,
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => '.localhost',
    'secure' => false,
    'httponly' => true
]
```

Comment: Make sure that the [**`session.cookie_path`**](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-path) and [**`session.cookie_domain`**](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain) configuration covers both of your applications locations, and inspect the headers that you receive and send to figure whether you a receiving and sending cookies, and what exactly they look like.

Comment: Can you please detail how to do that please ? I never did such a thing.

Comment: How to do what, checking your PHP configuration, or inspecting headers?

Comment: How to check session.cookie_path & session.cookie_domain's value, please.

Comment: Use for example [**`session_get_cookie_params()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-get-cookie-params.php).

Comment: Edited my post, the problem seems to come from the domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user ndm I came to this solution :

app.php :

```
'Session' => [
        'defaults' => 'php',
        'ini' => [
            'session.cookie_path' => '/',
            'session.cookie_domain' => 'localhost:8765'
        ]
    ]
```

Now using cakePHP's session in a normal file works just fine.

Thanks a lot ! :)